# Error: Not authorized, no token (authmiddleware.js file) in Mern Stack Application

Tags: node.js, authentication, redux, token, mern

So This is the most wierdest error I'm facing, It's been so many days since I'm trying to resolve this issue. but I couldn't. please assist me if someone can.

## About functionality of App

I'm building bus ticket booking system where I want my admin user to create,add,update and delete bus. I am able to create,add and delete bus but **not update** as it throws errow of token not found, though I'm sending the token.

//Front-End

**busSlice.js**
[I'm using redux slice concept here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaLcU.png)

```
export const updateBus = createAsyncThunk(
  "buses/edit",
  async (id, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await busService.updateBus(id, token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response &&
          error.response.data &&
          error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);
```

**busService.js**
[I'm clearly sending token here to backend, but still I'm receiving error of no token. Wierd thing is I have used same process for create,list and delete functionality adn it works fine there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z88C.png)

```
export const updateBus = async (id, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };
  console.log(token);
  const response = await axios.put(API_URL + id, config);
  return response.data;
};
```

//Back-End

**server.js**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9h8M.png)

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/buses", busRoutes);
```

**router.js**

```
import protect from "../middlewares/authMiddleware.js";

router.route("/").get(protect, getBuses).post(protect, createBus);
router
  .route("/:id")
  .get(protect, getBusById)
  .delete(protect, deleteBus)
  .put(protect, updateBus);
```

**authmiddleware.js**
[I get error of **Not authorized, no token**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNuyc.png)

```
const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;

  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    try {
      // Get token from header
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error("Not authorized");
    }
  }

  if (!token) {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Not authorized, no token");
  }
});
```

I have checked in postman, it works fine with bearer token applied. but when I'm trying from frontend it's causing error although same code works for create,list and delete. Btw I'm using jwt.

Can someone assist me in here? like what's the problem and how to resolve.

Comment: Which of `req.headers.authorization` and `req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")` is returning false?

Comment: Both are returning false! only happening for update.